# How to read a CSV in R from HTTP with AUTH

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a `CSV` with `R` from a `URL` that has `auth`, I do have the password and everything I just need to know what to add to the command, btw my password does include the `@` char so it messed up my scheme `[1]`

This is the command I'm trying:

```
products <- read.csv("http://username:pass@word@domain.com/api/products_by_date.csv?start_date=2011-04-01&end_date=2011-04-01", head=TRUE)
```

My output is:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : unable to resolve 'username'

[1] scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try `getURL` in the [RCurl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) package, which has the functionality to authenticate HTTP requests. see `?getURL` for an example.